# Need a link to go to a page and then return quickly to the current page

Tags: javascript, href

I am on a page and want to provide a link that will go to Pag 2 and then return to the current page (Page 1) quickly (user need to go to Page 2 for validation and then return to current page which is Page 1).

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>  

window.location.href="https://www.sitename.com/page2/?backurl="+window.location.replace="https://www.sitename.com/page1";  

</script> 

<p><a href="https://www.page2/">Go to Page 2 to Refresh and come back</a></p>
```

This doesn't work it stays on Page 2 and it doesn't automatically return to Page 1. How would I make this work in this way?

Comment: Why don't you use ajax for this?

Comment: Here's a link that does an ajax validation for some reference, http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will *only* run in the context in which it is initialized. Worded another way, a script that runs on page 1 will stop running as soon as page 2 loads. Different contexts.

You would need an additional script on page 2 that does a similar redirection back to page 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with javascript alone.    I would consider making an AJAX request to Pag 2 from Page 1.